# Matrix Invertible find a which is not invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For which ''a'' the following matrix
is not invertible?
$$\begin{pmatrix}a+1&1&1&1\\a+2&a&2&2\\a+2&1&a+2&2\\2a+3&1&1&a+3\end{pmatrix}$$

Basically , on a $2\times2$ and $3\times3$ I just have to calculate the determinant and for $D$ not equal to $0$ the matrix is invertible.Here I know its pretty much the same thing but the fact its a $4\times4$ matrix make it harder. Expanding the matrix using minor and cofactor would be a tedious task , so I thought about putting it into row echelon form and multiply the main diagonal.But im having issue reducing to row echelon form.
Any thought on this?

Comment: What issues are you facing when reducing to row echelon form?  It should be straightforward but tedious.  Letting us know the details of your attempt will enable us to help you better.  As you've already noted there are at least a couple ways to do this problem.  I think any way will be at least a little tedious.  Another option is to row reduce so that you get two or three zeros in one row or column, then do cofactor expansion.  The zeros will greatly simplify that.

Comment: Subtract the last column from the first, and take out the common factor from the new first column. The rest is simpler.

Comment: My main issue was with the ''a'' , but now I get it , thanks for the hints guys

Answer (score 2):

Ideas: first, substract row 1 from each of all other three rows:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a+1&1&1&1\\
1&a-1&1&1\\
1&0&a+1&1\\
a+2&0&0&a+2\end{vmatrix}\stackrel{C_4\to C_4-C_1}\longrightarrow\begin{vmatrix}
a+1&1&1&-a\\
1&a-1&1&0\\
1&0&a+1&0\\
a+2&0&0&0\end{vmatrix}\stackrel{\text{Develop 4th column}}=$$$${}$$

$$=a\begin{vmatrix}
1&a-1&1\\
1&0&a+1\\
a+2&0&0\end{vmatrix}\stackrel{\text{Develop 2nd column}}=-a(a-1)\begin{vmatrix}
1&a+1\\
a+2&0\end{vmatrix}=$$$${}$$

$$=a(a-1)(a+1)(a+2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Determinant will be a fourth degree equation with max four roots.

Trial and error gives:
$$a=0 \Rightarrow C1=C4,$$

$$a=-1 \Rightarrow R3=R4,$$

$$a=-2 \Rightarrow R1=R4.$$

$$a=1 \Rightarrow C1=C2+C4$$
Last case is a little hard. But note that $C1-C4$ results in all a's and $C2$ has all 1's but a. So assigning $a=1$ makes two columns equal.

Comment: I think you mean $a = 0 \implies C1 = C4$ and $a=1 \implies C1 = C2 + C4$.

Comment: @Robert Israel, thank you. Corrected.